# How to access from 1 class to other class struct

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner and trying to learn coding. So please excuse if my question is stupid. I have these 2 classes and I want the class Store to have access a data from struct Stock in class Toys. I'm not sure how can I do this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Toys {
public:
    struct Stock
    {
        int x;
        Stock(int value)
            :x(value) {}
    };
};

class Store {
public:
    Toys myToy(int count) {
        _count = count;
    }
    Toys* myStore;
    //What do I need to do to bind a struct Stock from class Toy here?
private:
    int _count;
};

int main()
{
    Store myStore;
    int x;
    std::vector<Toys::Stock> stocks;
    std::cout << "Enter the availability for Water Gun.\n";
    std::cin >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        stocks.push_back(i);
        std::cout << stocks[i].x << std::endl;
    }
//Later I want to pull vector stocks from class Store here.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose this class layout? Why is a stock a part of a toy? I don't think it should be. You couple the toy to the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Store as friend class of Toys which enables you to use data members of Toys class in Store class Try it !

Comment: But should you.... no

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd have to add a **friend declaration** saying that you want to access private data from a particular class but since in your given example `Stock` is a struct and since you've used `public` access specifier inside `Toys` while declaring `Stock`, there is **no need** for the friend declaration here.

This means, you can create an instance of type `Toys::Stock` inside `Store` without having any friend declaration as shown below:

```
class Store {
public:
    
    Toys* myStore;
    
    Toys::Stock s1; // a data member named `s1` of type Toys::Stock
  
    Toys::Stock* ptr; //a data member named `ptr` of type Toys::Stock*
    int _count;
};
```